# Keep mail going to old server while hosting on a new server

Tags: dns, mx

I'm trying to figure out how to keep mail going to an old server/MX record (which is the same as the domain for the website), after I change the A record for the domain.

Here's what I have now (with made up IP addresses):

```
example.com A 95.134.27.5 < old server
example.com MX example.com.
```

What I need is:

```
example A 12.9.149.143 < new server
example MX 95.134.27.5. < old server
```

Can I just use the IP address of the old server? Is there anything I need the current host to do to continue to have email processed through the old mail server?

Comment: Yes, MX records can hold IP adresses.

Comment: Thanks @DKOATED . The webmaster on the old host doesn't have other MX records I can point to, so I just have the IP address to continue directing to.